# Rails is not sending GET parameters to my :new controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a simples Users and Team many to many relationship and I am getting stuck at adding the users to Teams.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  has_secure_password
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

To keep it simple I decided not to use nested resources. So here are my routes for these resources:

```
resources :users
resources :teams
resources :memberships, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

In my team's :show action I put a button there so one can go to a page to add users to the team:

```
<%= button_to new_membership_path(team_id: @team.id), class: 'btn btn-default', method: :get do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Integrantes
<% end %>
```

Note that I am passing a GET parameter to the new_membership_path function call so when I reach the memberships#new action it will know the group we are referring to.

The path generated by the code below is correct:

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/memberships/new?team_id=1">        
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Integrantes
  </button>
</form>
```

However, I am getting this error when clicking the button:

```
Couldn't find Team with 'id'=
```

And that's because the params variable is empty! (ref. attached image).

Here is my controller code: http://pastebin.com/t2ZevNtH

My understanding is that any parameter sent over through GET or POST would end up in that variable.

Did I miss anything here? Thank you!

[Attachment Image: Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV7HV.png)

Comment: Can you post your controller code please.

Comment: Done @japed! Let me know if you need any other info. The error actually happens on a callback I have to set the @team variable which expects the team_id to be sent over the params.

Comment: Could you post  `show` action? Thats where the `@team` variable should be set.

Comment: I actually do not have a show action. At this time I am just rendering the new action so I can manage the memberships. Meaning that I will just select the users that will be part of the group.

Comment: Can you post the whole controller code.

Comment: Here it is @japed: http://pastebin.com/t2ZevNtH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get that working! Thanks Cuong Nguyen Minh!

Seems that I should create the button like this in the Team's view:

```
<%= link_to new_membership_path(team_id: @team.id), type: 'button', method: :get do %>
  <%= button_tag class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Adicionar
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way I see the params being populated by the GET parameters in the Memberships' action!

Thank you everyone for replying to my doubt with awesome tips and so fast!

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the *team_id* into form as a hidden input.

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/memberships/new">
  <input type='hidden' name='team_id' value='1'>        
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Integrantes
  </button>
</form>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: You've hardcoded `team_id` to `1`, that woun't solve the problem.

Comment: The html code I pasted there is actually generated by the button_to and it's not wrapped by a form so I can't add a hidden field. It should be past through a GET parameter in the url.

Comment: Perhaps you should use link_to here.
<%= link_to "Integrantes", new_membership_path(team_id: @team.id), class: 'btn btn-default' %>

Answer (score 1):

> I decided not to use nested resources.

<s>What you have are *not* [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). *These* are nested (note the levels of indentation etc)</s> Sorry I'm kind of tired:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :memberships, only: [:index, :create, :destroy] #-> url.com/users/:user_id/memberships/new
end
resources :teams
```

This means you're able to call the following:

```
#app/views/teams/show.html.erb
<%= button_to "Integrantes", new_user_membership_path(user_id: [[user]].id, team_id: @team.id), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the `[[user]]` -- this is meant to denote your *user* object. Most of the time this will be `current_user` (if you're using `Devise`) - I can amend the answer to include it if you're specific on how it's created.

```
#app/controllers/memberships_controller.rb
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @membership = Membership.new membership_params
      @membership.team = Team.find params[:team_id]
      @membership.user = User.find params[:user_id]
   end

   private

   def membership_params
     params.require(:membership).permit(:membership, :params)
   end
end
```

This could be improved a lot, but will hopefully get your error resolved

Comment: Thanks Rich! Let me try your solution and see if it solves the issue!